# Does depedent project in java take log4j config of parent project?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, dependencies, log4j

I am having project A and project B, A has jar dependency of project B. I have defined log4j.xml in project A but I am not able to see logs of sub-project(B.jar) in file appender as well as tomcat server console. Does project B will take log4j.xml form parent project A or not then which config does it use?

Comment: Please help me configure log4j such that all applications running on tamcat server uses same log config.

Comment: Tomcat is a containerized environment.  Each WAR will get its own configuration.

Answer (score 1):

There is one log4j config for your entire JVM (unless you're working in a containerized environment using class loaders and....  that's not what's described).

Missing log messages implies that the configuration from log4j either (a) isn't what you think it is (i.e. a different log4j.xml is being used) or (b) doesn't have the right settings for the missing log lines.

Adding the following to the JVM at startup may help:

```
-Dlog4j.debug
```

It may also be possible to browse the log4j settings via MBeans in jconsole.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all apps (WAR files) in a Tomcat instance to have the same logging configs, the simple solution is to arrange that all WAR files have a **copy** of the same config file.

If you want the apps to share a common logging framework (with a single configuration), then you should consider using Context Selectors, as described in the [Log4j 2 documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/logsep.html).

> ### Using Context Selectors
>
> There are a few patterns for achieving the desired state of logging separation using `ContextSelectors`:
>
> 1. Place the logging jars in the container's classpath and set the system property `log4j2.contextSelector` to `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.BasicContextSelector`. This will create a single `LoggerContext` using a single configuration that will be shared across all applications.
> 2. Place the logging jars in the container's classpath and use the default `ClassLoaderContextSelector.` Follow the instructions to initialize Log4j 2 in a web application. Each application can be configured to share the same configuration used at the container or can be individually configured. If status logging is set to debug in the configuration there will be output from when logging is initialized in the container and then again in each web application.
> 3. Follow the instructions to initialize Log4j 2 in a web application and set the system property or servlet context parameter `log4j2.contextSelector` to `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.JndiContextSelector`. This will cause the container to use JNDI to locate each web application's `LoggerContext`. Be sure to set the `isLog4jContextSelectorNamed` context parameter to true and also set the `log4jContextName` and `log4jConfiguration` context parameters.
>
> The exact method for setting system properties depends on the container. For Tomcat, edit `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/catalina.properties`. Consult the documentation for other web containers.

I don't think there is a direct equivalent in Log4j 1.x.